# Drop "is" prefix for Firebase Firestore fields for Boolean Values

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

When using custom Kotlin objects for firestore drop 'is' prefix. It ruined my entire day.

```
data class UberRequest(val geoPoint: GeoPoint? = null,
                   
                   //don't use 'is' prefix on boolean properties
                   val isAccepted:Boolean = false,
                   @ServerTimestamp
                   val timestamp: Date? = null)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firestore uses [Java Bean conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) for mapping properties between the Java class and the JSON in the database.

In Java Beans an `is` prefix on a boolean field/method indicates a boolean property. So the fact that your `isAccepted` is mapped to a JSON property with the name `accepted` is expected.

---

If you want to control the name that Firebase uses in its JSON mapping, you can annotate the field/methods with `@PropertyName("isAccepted")`.

Comment: [@PropertyName](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/PropertyName) can possibly work around this.

Answer (score 2):

I noted on the console that 'is' is dropped as shown on this snapshot from firestore console
[image]

So when you try to retrieve the isAccepted value **it returns the default value which in this case is false**. If the default value is null, you get a null value back

This is illustrated on this snapshot from my logcat

[image]

Comment: This should have been part of the question (which you can edit), not an answer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you are right it should be part of the question.