# Prevent firebase from taking the method name as variable in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

In my `android` application, I was setting an object in firebase. The class contain a method called `isValid` as below

```
data class SomeClass(
    var a: Int? = null,
    var b: Int? = null
) {

    fun isValid(): Boolean {
        return a != null && b != null
    }
}
```

When I set the object for this class, My firebase real-time database snapshot was created as below.

[image]

How do I will prevent adding the variable 'valid' in firebase?

**Edit:**
I used the following code to set the data in firebase

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("abc").setValue(SomeClas(1, 3))
```

Comment: Can you share your code that adds data to Firebase ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj, Please find my edit

Comment: When your assigning it as integer. Then Just remove the `?` which will make it `non-nullable`. Rest will be handled by exception

Comment: @Ashish, This is just an example. Not actual code. the problem is the variable `valid` is coming in firebase

Comment: @shafeeq put the actual code

Comment: That is similar. I cannot expose it here. It's confidential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is due to the prefix 'is'. I had seen the same behavior when we use set or get prefix in the method. In your case, as a workaround rename `isValid` method to `valid.`

Comment: The reason for that can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63980305/13130697)

Comment: Good catch Aims Manjeri! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If someone still want to use the prefix "is" in kotlin, I can help you with this simple code.

```kotlin
data class(
    @get:PropertyName("isValid")
    val isValid:Boolean=false
)
```